# Finding optimal combination of parameters for clustering

Tags: clustering, optimization, algorithms

I have a spreadsheet with one object per line. Each column contains values that are parameters of my objects (let's say length, width, height, weight, color). I can classify objects based on color and define classes.

Let's say I am blind, and I therefore don't have access to the color parameter. I want to find a combination of the other parameters that can categorize my objects by color with decent accuracy.
Is there a way to find this combination of parameters, or do I have to brute force it and test every combination?

Comment: Do you need to predict the colors of *your* objects only or is your intention to predict the colors of objects not yet listed in your dataset?

Comment: @whuber I'd like to predict the color of future objects whose color will be unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you define color? If you define color as an image file, there will be strong signals separating one color from another. If you do not have access to that sort of information, you can use a multinomial logistic regression, LDA  like model or any of the other zillion classification models.

Remember that, brute force is never the way to go (unless problem size is extremely small). Combinatorial problems go out of hand very fast.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me toward logistic regression, I think that's exactly what I was looking for. Reading about it now.